# My onChange method is taking the previous value

Tags: reactjs

I have the following code:

```
handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
    console.log(this.state.value);
  }
```

Create options:

```
 populateSelectGroup() {
    return this.state.groups.map((group, index) => {
      const { IdGroup, NameGroup } = group; // destructor
      // console.log(IdGroup);
      return <option key={index} value={IdGroup} label={NameGroup} />;
    });
  }
```

Component:

```
// MY COMPONENT
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="wrap_Content_Inside">
        <div className="component">
          <select
            name="Installations"
            id="groupInstallations"
            value={this.state.value}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          >
            {this.populateSelectGroup()}
          </select>
        </div>
        <div className="component1_2">
          <table className="list">
            <tbody ref={this.ref}>{this.populateBodyInstallationsEdition()}</tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default EditionGroup;
```

My problem is, if I click on option 1 (Name: group 1, ID: 1) and then click on option 2 (Name: group 2, ID: 2) it returns me the id of the previous option that was clicked.

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: setState is aynchronous, so you may not access the changed state immediately. 
Also can you add your state definition to the question?

Comment: Worth trying to convert the `populateSelectGroup` statement to expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setState` is asynchronous, so `console.log(this.state.values)` may print the previous state value, you can passs a callback if you want to invoke a function or do something after the setState.
You need to change `handleChange` as below to get updated state

```
handleChange(event) {
  this.setState({ value: event.target.value }, () => {
    console.log(this.state.value)
  });

}
```

Comment: this solve my problem, i didn't know i could callback.